# Kernel Compilation option with "Core Dump Generate Enabled when "Kernel Panic on oops

Tags: linux, kernel

I am a newbie on Linux Kernel. And I am doing the simple things what I describe below.

I try to compile Linux Kernel Version 4.19 on Ubuntu 18.04.

My Mission is to compile the Kernel which Core Dump be generated when "Kernel Panic on Oops"

But I cannot find that option. Actually I think that I could modify the option through menuconfig GUI Interface.

How Could I modify it? or Basically My mission is not a valid? (like Core Dump always be generated, it is not the region of compile and so on...)

Comment: According to [this site](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/PANIC_ON_OOPS.html), the option is named `PANIC_ON_OOPS`. You may find it in `make menuconfig` GUI via searching.

Comment: Simple and nice comment Thanks a lot :)